# Bash prepends the symbol '@' to $PS1. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: bash, prompt

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and bash keeps putting '@' in front of my prompt, regardless of the value set in `~/.bashrc`.

I've tried setting different values both in the `~/.bashrc` file and from within the terminal using the `export` command.

For example, this is a segment of my terminal:

```
@$ export PS1='HELLO '
@HELLO
```

I even tried reverting back to the [original `~/.bashrc`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/marioBonales/1637696/raw/93a33aa5f1893f46773483250214f8b8b496a270/.bashrc) , but with no success because that @ is still there in every line.

- Is there a way to get rid of it?
- Is there another configuration file I should be looking at?
- Is it a bug that I should report?

Comment: Is there any $PROMPT_COMMAND?

Comment: @choroba nope, undefined

Comment: Call `set -x` command to debug the command line. Basically it should show what is being executed each time. To stop it, run `set +x` Let us know if that reveals anything. Clearly you have something set somewhere, maybe /etc/bash_bashrc  . . . Can recall if that's correct file or not off the top of my head

Comment: @Serg `set -x` did not reveal any hidden commands and searching for `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` did not return any results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You appear to have configured `readline` to enable *edit mode indication*. From [8.3.1 Readline Init File Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html) of the Bash Reference Manual:

```
show-mode-in-prompt (Off)
       If set to On, add a character to the  beginning  of  the  prompt
       indicating  the  editing  mode:  emacs (@), vi command (:) or vi
       insertion (+).
```

You should be able to disable it in the current shell using

```
bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt off'
```

To disable it persistently, you will need to find where it is getting set, possibly your `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` files.

Comment: thanks, this fixed it for me. I had the ~/.inputrc set to on. Switched to off, no more @ prepended to $PS1